# Calling stopService in onActivityResult() is not effective

Tags: android, service

In onActivityResult, I wanted to stop and restart the service. But now I'm not even able to stop the service with the code below.

```
if (requestCode == DEVICE_SELECTION)
{
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
            stopService(i);
        }
}
```

In debugging mode, it is able to reach the stopService() line, but the app never calls the onDestroy() of MyService class (which extends the Service class) and the service is not destroyed.

Does anyone have any idea why that is the case?

My service can be started properly and I am able to destroy the service when stopService() is called in onDestroy() method of the Activity which indicates to me that my service class is implemented correctly.

Comment: Is this all of your code?  You say you want to stop *and* restart the service.  If you restart before it actually stops, it won't stop.

Comment: @KevinKrumwiede Please see a more complete code in my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I need to call unbindService() before I destroy the service by calling stopService(). Otherwise, the service doesn't get destroyed.

The code below works for the purpose I intended: the stop the service and restart the service with a different device (this is for a bluetooth device).

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == DEVICE_SELECTION)
    {
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK)
        {
            String name = data.getExtras()
                    .getString(DeviceListActivity.EXTRA_DEVICE_NAME);
            currentDevice = name;
            Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class);
            if(i != null){
                if (isBound){
                    unbindService(myServiceConnection); // <-- Unbind the service first
                }
                stopService(i);
            }
            i.putExtra("MY_DEVICE", currentDevice);
            startService(i);
            bindService(i,myServiceConnection,Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
        }
    }
}
```

The only thing I'm not sure of is which one is a good practice: creating a new Intent for starting and stoping service or using the same Intent? Both of them seem to work.

Comment: unbindService is needed if you have provided IP binder then service will continue to run untill all apps remove their binding, else stopservice would ideally stop your service. I am still confused, can you please share your service code if possible ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to cache the intent from where you have started the service then use the same intent to stop the service, It will work

for example lets say Intent i = new Intent(this, MyService.class); was the intent which you used to start a service startService(i) , use same intent to stop it. don't create new intent.

Comment: Thanks, I have tried this and still doesn't work. Besides my onDestroy() creates a new intent instead of using a cached one and that works.